# complicated command replace in files using sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

I want to replace the below strings

replace: **print 'Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code)**

with: **print('Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code))**

Here is the command I ran which fails

```
find ./ -type f -exec  gsed 's/'print 'Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code)'/'print('Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code))'/g' {} \;
```

I tried to use \ to avoid the special characters effect but still fails too and just hangs.

```
find ./ -type f -exec  gsed -i 's/print \'Status Code: {code}\'.format\(code=r.status_code\)/print\(\'Status Code: {code}\'.format\(code=r.status_code\)\)/g' {} \;
> 
> 
>
```

Comment: (Please do NOT close and mark this as duplicate by simply referencing a generic sed or perl question, I've spent more than a few hours trying to research this on stackExchange and web without any hopes )

Comment: That doesn't make it less of a duplicate... This has been asked so many times it's even boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use double quotes around the expression, or close and re-open the single quotes around each literal `'`, like `'\''`:

```
sed "s/print 'Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code)/print('Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code))/"
```

```
sed 's/print '\''Status Code: {code}'\''.format(code=r.status_code)/print('\''Status Code: {code}'\''.format(code=r.status_code))/'
```

Comment: @steeldriver....you are simply awesome thank you